# Can I connect the jdbc connected static Derby data file in remote repository?

Tags: derby

I have to load two Derby instances that reference same data Derby file in a remote repository.

Is it possible? How can I achieve this? Would you give detailed information?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: what do you mean? I tried with the mode, "Generic Derby (Embedded)" and the jdbc url, "jdbc:derby:\\remoteipaddress\\derby-file;create=true" is it ok?

Comment: Do you mean to create two connections to the same NetworkServer? That is ok. Two connections (in separate threads, but same jvm) to an embedded database? Also ok. Two jvms accessing the same database in embedded mode? not ok

Comment: Thank you very much. Accessing the database with embedded mode  is like handling a local file. How can two threaDS in ine JVM can be OK? I wanted two jvms to access same database in embeded mode. But now I agree that my idea was wrong definitely.

Answer (score 2):

Two different connections in the same Derby app is ok because Derby uses Java synchronization features to coordinate their access to the db.

Two different apps cannot use Java synchronization because that only works inside a single Jvm  class loader so instead Derby locks the db and only allows one app at a time to access the db.

That is the benefit of the Derby network server because many apps can access the db simultaneously via the network server.

There is a hybrid mode by which one embedded app can also serve as the network server for other apps but it is complex and usually not the best choice.

**Update:** You can find more information about embedded servers in these docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/cadminov825149.html and http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/radminembeddedserverex.html
or by searching the Internet for "Derby embedded server".

Comment: I am late. thanks for your elaborate reply. how can i configure the hybrid mode?

Comment: Updated the answer with some additional pointers to embedded server  info.

Comment: @verystrongjoe: this looks like a helpful answer. Would you consider accepting it? To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so it turns green. This marks the question as resolved and awards a few points to the helper to thank them for their time.